# How to hook a debugger to a python code running via django crontab?

Tags: django, python-3.x, cron, django-cron

I have a Django based web application, some functionality of the application is scheduled to be run as a part of cron jobs using [django-crontab](https://pypi.org/project/django-crontab/). I want to hook a debugger so that I can inspect some odd behaviours of my code. I normally use visual studio code. Is it possible to hook a debugger, since cron jobs basically run independently apart from server?

Comment: Do you want to do that in your production server?

Comment: nope, my local first and then test server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a breaking point debugger in the code using [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html) or [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb/). Like this:

```
def some_function():
    # some code
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()  # or use ipdb
    # rest of the code
```

Then in shell, run `python manage.py crontab show` to show cronjobs with **ids**, then run `python manage.py crontab run <id>`. It will hit the debugger, then you will hit the breaking point. Thus you can use debugger here.

Comment: Is there any way I can hook into my editor's debugger for instance VS Code?

Comment: I have not tried, so I can't say for sure. You can try to launch the debugger with above command `python manage.py crontab run <id>`. But, using PDB is pretty much the standard.

Comment: Thanks, well still new to python and that command line approach is not too much interactive ;-)